# Is it possible to send push notification to multiple Android applications without manually registering it in Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to notify updates from server to a set of android applications. I want to know whether it is possible with Firebase push notification service without manually registering the apps. If it is not, please help me with any other solution.

Comment: I don't think there is any other way of adding other than through the Firebase Console, but what's your scenario?

Comment: I have a set of android applications. I like to register only one of those apps with firebase console. But every app (not registered with firebase console)should get a notification from server in case of updates.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're trying to do. But if you want to notify a number of users of your app about a specific condition, you can have those users' app subscribe to a specific topic. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

Comment: In topic messaging also we need to manually create every apps in firebase consle, right? That is not my scenario.

Comment: @Aparna.M I deleted my answer. I'm having a hard time figuring out what you mean, but if it's about allowing the apps to receive a notification **without registration**, I don't think that's possible.